# Java auto increment issue

Tags: java, oop, auto-increment

I'm having trouble with this requirement. I have this snippet:

```
    private String id;
    private int age;
    private static int index;

    public Customer(int a) {
          this.id = a + "C" + index;
          index++;
          this.age = a;
    }
```

It works fine. But the thing is, I want for every age the index will be reset to 1, like <10C1, 10C2> when there are 2 10-year-old customers and if you create a new customer with the age of 20 it will go back to <20C1,20C2,..>. Since there are no restriction to the age so the if statement seems not possible.

Comment: Instead of keeping one static variable index, you should keep a map with age as key and index as value. ConcurrentHashMap will be good for this.

Comment: Use a Map. Or create your own data structure.

Comment: @Thomas: thank you, I just tried ConcurrentHashMap and it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static map in user:

```
private String id;
private int age;
private static map indexMap = new HashMap();

public Customer(int a) {
      this.id = a + "C" + index;
      index++;
      this.age = a;
}

public synchronized static int getIndexOfAge(int age) {
    if (!indexMap.contains(age)) {
        indexMap.put(age, 1);
    }
    int theIndex = indexMap.get(age);
    theIndex++;
    indexMap.put(age, theIndex);
}
```

But I have to say this is really not a good way to code. You should use something like UserIndexFactory to create user index. You should also consider the thread safe and performance.

Comment: thanks a bunch :D it is just an exercise. I got it working now :)